# Extend IRB main methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, irb, hirb

I have a directory structure in my app. For development purposes (and possibly beyond), I currently have a class `X` which has class methods `pwd`, `cd`, and `ls`. Is there a way to make these methods available when I enter `irb` whithin my app, for example:

```
2.1.5 :0 > pwd
/current_dir/
```

Currently I am doing:

```
2.1.5 :0 > X.pwd
/current_dir/
```

which is simply inconvenient.

A solution where I could simply add something to my existing class would be perfect, like:

```
class X < Irb::main
  def self.pwd
    #stuff
  end
end
```

Right now I don't really dig `hirb`, but if there is a solution that works with `hirb` or `irb`, I'll give it a shot! Thanks for your help!

Comment: https://github.com/janlelis/irbtools

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Rails, you can conditionally mix methods into the console when the Rails app is started via IRB.

This is done using the `console` configuration block in your `application.rb` file.

```
module MyApp
  class Application < Rails::Application

    # ...

    console do
      # define the methods here
    end

  end
end
```

In your case, there are several possibilities. You can simply delegate the methods to your library.

```
module MyApp
  class Application < Rails::Application
    console do

      # delegate pwd to X
      def pwd
        X.pwd
      end

    end
  end
end
```

or if X is a module, you can include it

```
module MyApp
  class Application < Rails::Application
    console do
      Rails::ConsoleMethods.send :include, X
    end
  end
end
```